# Given a set $S$ of size $n$ and $A \subseteq S$ of size $k$, how many subsets of $S$ contain $A$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $S$ of size $n$ and $A \subseteq S$ of size $k$, how many subsets of $S$ contain $A$?

I know that the number of subsets contained in $S$ is $2^n$ but how do I find how many subsets of $S$ containing $A$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the subset contains $A$, so fix it first. Then you have for the remaining $|S|-|A|$ elements, how many choices?

**Hint:** Either they are part of subset or they are not.

Comment: Slight error., you seem to have confused the letters $k$ and $n$.  The size of $S$ is $n$.  The size of $A$ is $k$.  So, rather than $k-|A|$ "remaining elements" there are $n-k$ remaining elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh yes! I misread it i think! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

note that every subset $M$ of $S$ $M\subseteq S$ which is exists $|M|\ge k$ can theoretically contain $A$. of course not every$M$ such that $|M| \ge  k$ contains $A$.

therefore, for every $M$ which contain $A$, there are extra $n-k$ elements of $S$ which are allowed to be remover from $M$ such that $A\subseteq M$ will be a truth statement.

try to figure out how many combinations of a set like that exists.